# syntax error at or near "(" postgresql + Python

Tags: postgresql, export-to-csv, psycopg2, postgresql-8.0

I'm using a Jupyter notebook for working with some database with postgresql
I have the following instances:

```
import pandas as pd
import (other packages)
conn_string= % I can't show this, but this is ok
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor=conn.cursor
query= """ copy (select col1,col2 from Table where col3=a_parameter
           and col4=b_parameter) to '/tmp/test.csv' with csv """
pd.read_sql(query,conn)
```

But I got this error:

```
**ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: COPY (select col1,col2 from Table where col3...**
             ^
```

Why the copy sentence has an error?
**I am using Postresql  8.0.2**

Comment: Your ancient version [did not support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-copy.html) a select statement in the `COPY` command. _If_ you are using an outdated version, you should also read the manual for that version, not for newer versions. You should upgrade to a supported and maintained version **now**.

Comment: Please upgrade your Postgres. We have 10 now and it's been many years since version 8.

Comment: I'm working with Jupyter Notebook + Python 3.4+ psycopg2 (which allows me to do postgresql querys). How can I upgrade? 
Is there any option to export data to csv?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this:

```
query= """ copy (select col1,col2 from Table where col3=a_parameter
       and col4=b_parameter) """

df=pd.read_sql(query,con=conn)
df.to_csv("name.csv",sep=",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
import csv
            my_file_csv =  my_folder + "\Report_Trip_Day_" + my_opr + "_" + my_local_database + ".csv"


            out = csv.writer(open(my_file_csv, "w", newline=''), delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            out.writerow(colnames)
            for row in my_xls_report_table:
                out.writerow(row)
```